# setting value in a migration

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So currently my table has a `date`, and a date index, I want to drop the date index, add a `start_date` and `end_date`, and initially set both the start and end date equal to whatever `date` was, and then add start and end date indexes. Can this all be done in one migration? How would that look?

Comment: What have you been trying so far? You can have a look in ecto_sql doc https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#fragment/1

Comment: Besides `fragment/1`, migration is still nothing but plain old good SQL. The task can definitely be accomplished with pure SQL and then executed with [`Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#query!/4).

Comment: @TheAnh fragment looks ok for something in plain sql, but I need to access data from the specific row, is that possible with fragment?

Answer (score 1):

```
def up do
  alter table(:table) do
    add :start_date, :date
    add :end_date, :date
  end

  execute "update table set start_date=date, end_date=date"

  alter table(:table) do
    remove :date
  end

  create index(:table, :start_date)
  create index(:table, :end_date)
end
```

Index will for `date` will be removed with field removal.